# ¿Se puede crear una API de una base de datos de Visual FoxPro?

Tags: api, visual-foxpro

En mi empresa, queremos acceder directamente a la base de datos del ERP SAI sin tener que abrir la aplicación. Esto nos lleva mucho tiempo, ya que tenemos que generar un reporte y pegarlo en Excel, etc.

El ERP se maneja con Visual FoxPro y podemos acceder a sus tablas, pero son archivos .DBF. Quiero poder hacer una API para evitar generar reportes y poder generar nuestros indicadores de la empresa llamando a esta API.

¿Alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer una API desde Visual FoxPro?

He intentado crear un CSV a partir del .DBF, pero como son demasiados datos, esto también es una pérdida de tiempo.

Pretendo utilizar Django para exponer la API de manera local, ya que solo necesitamos que una computadora (aparte del servidor) pueda leer estos datos. Sin embargo, no tengo ningún conocimiento de cómo funciona Visual FoxPro.

No puedo mostrar un error específico, ya que no sé cómo empezar. Por eso, necesito al menos una orientación sobre este tema. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme, estaría muy agradecido. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es poco específica. Actualmente la respuesta es: *Sí, se puede*. Creo que debes empezar por establecer la tecnología con la que vas a implementar tu API, luego, cuando tengas un problema específico, puedes volver por aquí, explicando con detalle el problema, para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, pero no tengo un problema como tal en específico, pues no sé como se maneja Visual FoxPro, solo requiero un poco de orientación en ello para poder yo generar la API. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Es muy complejo el proyecto como para migrarlo? Al parecer no se ha actualizado desde 2007. Aun asi, puede que [esto te sirva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37553/4326551)

Comment: no entiendo mucho el sentido de la pregunta.. vsfp es una cosa.. django es python... que tiene que ver una cosa con la otra? igual, asi como esta, seria basada en opiniones :(

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta depende del caso o escenario que manejas:

- Si la base de datos ya no esta siendo actualizada (sus datos ya no tienen modificaciones), lo mejor es exportarla a otro tipo de base de datos que puedas usar en Django. (ejemplo, exportar a Excel y luego importar a una base de datos). Existe el comando `EXPORT` para realizar esta operacion (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/foxpro/aa977646(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- De otra manera, si deseas que los datos sean accesibles en tiempo real tendrias que usar alguna libreria para leer .DBF como dbfread (https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

**Si puedes crear un API**, con cualquier lenguaje o herramienta que cumpla estos dos requisitos:

- Que sea capaz de leer datos desde tablas de FoxPro (.dbf), según has dicho que necesitas
- Que tenga la capacidad de exponer un API de la manera que te interesa, por ejemplo, un WebAPI, que es lo que está de moda.

Si es para reportes, incluso puedes hacer una herramienta o página web que exponga los reportes como tal (y no todo un API).